# How to Dynamically use a table from SSIS expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have Variable [User::Tablename1] String, I need an Expression that can evaluate at runtime, to check,

```
If Tablename1 is 'Customer'
       select * from dbo.Customer where CustID = 1
Else If Tablename1 is any other tablename
       "select * from dbo"**Tablename** where ProdID= 1
```

My concern is how to make the tablename dynamic and the filter column.

Comment: Use expressions. I guess you want this in a SQL Source? Keep in mind these tables must have identical columns (including data types), or SSIS will throw an error due to mappings.

Comment: My idea would be to set variable by default to 2nd query `select * from dbo**Tablename** where ProdID= 1` and use expression to check if `[User::Tablename1] == 'Customer'`, then set the 1st query if expression is true... On Database Source/Destination just use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should create two variables with these texts in the expression for your Select variables:

```
1: "select * from dbo."+[User::Tablename1]+ "where ProdID= 1"
2: "select * from dbo.Customer where CustID = 1"
```

Then you can use a sql command text for getting your table names and pass them as a input to a for each loop container to set it to your [User::Tablename1] variable.
In the for each you can use one Expression Task to compare 'Customer' with your [User::Tablename1] value.
At the end, by using the green arrow of the button of expression task, you can set the constraint with the result output. If the result is yes you can execute the Second select, else you execute the first select with any given table name.